# Rails 3.2.13: Routing Error (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/application.css")

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Update**

Here are the search results for 'asset' in my app (excluding log).

> ./app/assets/javascripts/application.js:4:// Any JavaScript/Coffee
>   file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts,
>   vendor/assets/javascripts,
>
> ./app/assets/javascripts/application.js:5:// or
>   vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here
>   using a relative path.
>
> ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:5: *
>   Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets,
>   vendor/assets/stylesheets,
>
> ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:6:
>   * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
>
> ./config/application.rb:7:  # If you
>   precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
>
> ./config/application.rb:8:  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets =>
>   %w(development test)))
>
> ./config/application.rb:9:  # If you want your
>   assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
>
> ./config/application.rb:10:  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets,
>   Rails.env)
>
> ./config/application.rb:54:    # Enable the asset pipeline
>
> ./config/application.rb:55:    config.assets.enabled = true
>
> ./config/application.rb:57:    # Version of your assets, change this
>   if you want to expire all your assets
>
> ./config/application.rb:58:   config.assets.version = '1.0'
>
> ./config/environments/development.rb:9: 
>   config.assets.enabled = false
>
> ./config/environments/development.rb:34: # Do not compress assets
>
> ./config/environments/development.rb:35:  config.assets.compress = false
>   ./config/environments/development.rb:37:  # Expands the lines which
>   load the assets
>
> ./config/environments/development.rb:38: 
>   config.assets.debug = true
>
> ./config/environments/production.rb:11:  #
>   Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do
>   this)
>
> ./config/environments/production.rb:12: 
>   config.serve_static_assets = true
>
> ./config/environments/production.rb:15:  config.assets.compress = true
>
> ./config/environments/production.rb:17:  # Don't fallback to assets
>   pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
>
> ./config/environments/production.rb:18:  config.assets.compile = true
>
> ./config/environments/production.rb:20:  # Generate digests for assets
>   URLs
>
> ./config/environments/production.rb:21:  config.assets.digest =
>   true
>
> ./config/environments/production.rb:23:  # Defaults to
>   Rails.root.join("public/assets")
>
> ./config/environments/production.rb:24:  # config.assets.manifest =
>   YOUR_PATH
>
> ./config/environments/production.rb:45:  # Enable serving of
>   images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
>
> ./config/environments/production.rb:46:  #
>   config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"
>
> ./config/environments/production.rb:48:  # Precompile additional
>   assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are
>   already added)
>
> ./config/environments/production.rb:49:  #
>   config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )
>
> ./config/environments/test.rb:10:  # Configure static asset server for
>   tests with Cache-Control for performance
>
> ./config/environments/test.rb:11:  config.serve_static_assets = true
>
> ./Gemfile:30:# Gems used only for assets and not required
>
> ./Gemfile:32:group :assets do ./README.rdoc:159:  |   |-- assets
>
> ./README.rdoc:192:      |-- assets ./README.rdoc:199:app/assets

I also tried including the asset tags in raw html, as in `<script src="assets/application.js"></script>`, but it didn't work either.

---

I'm working on a `Rails 3.2.13` app and have encountered the following problem:
the app/assets files don't seem to get run!

In my **application.html.erb** file:

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

When I run `rails server`, I see the following error message in the log:

```
Started GET "/stylesheets/application.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-20 15:34:51
-0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/application .css"):
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in ` call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13)lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'

Rendered
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb
 within resc ues/layout (1.0ms)
```

At the same time, there are error messages for the other assets as well (js files, css etc).  Another example:

```
Started GET "/javascripts/application.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-07-20
15:34:51 - 0400 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/application .js"): ...
```

I've tried restarting the server, restarting my computer, but it doesn't help. 
I have also attempted copying development.rb and production.rb files from other functional apps, but no effect either.

Can anyone please help?

---

Here are my assets search path, by running  `Rails.application.config.assets.paths`:

> ["c:/Users/user/rails_projects/fyff/app/assets/images",
>   "c:/Users/user/rails_ projects/fyff/app/assets/javascripts",
>   "c:/Users/user/rails_projects/fyff/app/as sets/stylesheets",
>   "c:/Users/user/rails_projects/fyff/vendor/assets/javascripts" ,
>   "c:/Users/user/rails_projects/fyff/vendor/assets/stylesheets",
>   "c:/RailsInstal
>   ler/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts ",
>   "c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/best_in_place-1
>   152e2256afd/lib/assets/javascripts",
>   "c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/
>   1.9.1/bundler/gems/bootstrap-switch-rails-2cb6f83ee23e/vendor/assets/javascripts
>   ",
>   "c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/bootstrap-switc
>   h-rails-2cb6f83ee23e/vendor/assets/stylesheets",
>   "c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/li
>   b/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jquery-rails-3.0.1/vendor/assets/javascripts",
>   "c:/RailsI
>   nstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bootstrap-sass-2.3.2.0/vendor/assets
>   /images",
>   "c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bootstrap-sass-2
>   .3.2.0/vendor/assets/javascripts",
>   "c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.
>   9.1/gems/bootstrap-sass-2.3.2.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets"]

which looks just fine to me...

Comment: I see a space between file name and .js & .css

Comment: How do you include those in your layout?

Comment: using the conventional include tags, as in update

Comment: Do you have asset pipeline enabled? Valid asset pipeline link should be `assets/application.js/.css`

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more on that?  Where should I expect to see that valid pipeline link, or whether I have asset pipeline enabled?

Comment: Take a look at the Rails guides chapter http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: And I fixed an error you made in title and desc - log says you use 3.2.13 not 3.2.1!

Comment: thanks, in my config/application.rb, I have a line 'config.assets.enabled = true', so I think it's enabled

Comment: Yeah, but the links generated are somehow wrong. Go through this guide and see if everything else is set properly.

Comment: the application.js/css manifests and the assets search paths (as in update) look fine to me. I'll keep looking

Comment: here's an anomaly that I don't understand: in my layouts/application.html.erb, the include tags generated the following html - <link href="/stylesheets/application.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><script src="/javascripts/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

as opposed to the correct display: http://monosnap.com/image/uNGLouz44cLWCeh4lKmI3eayB.  Do you have any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Can you search your whole codebase for `asset` and post result? There must be some setting changed

Comment: it's strange though, all the lines involving assets look just fine to me...

Comment: hey @MichaelSzyndel, here's what I did and worked - start a new rails project and copy everything over. Thanks for all your help! Can you move your responses to the answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Come on, I didn't help at all and we still don't know what was the reason! MAybe you can diff those two projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by creating a new application and moving all the files there.  Asset pipeline now functioning normally.

Answer (score 8):

I was getting this error and solved it by running:

RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile

Answer (score 1):

You had a space after application .css