# Rails bundle install - failed to build gem native extension for JSON

Tags: ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

I was trying to fix a [strange problem in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766050/rails-3-2-13-routing-error-no-route-matches-get-stylesheets-application-cs) so I resorted to uninstalling all the gems (using a command found here: http://geekystuff.net/2009/01/14/remove-all-ruby-gems/) and then running `bundle install`.

The removal was successful, but when I ran `bundle install`, I got the following error:

> Installing activeresource (3.2.13)
>
> Using bundler (1.3.5) Installing
>   rack-ssl (1.3.3)
>
> Installing json (1.8.0)
>
> Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native
>   extension .
>
> ```
>     c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb creating Makefile
> ```
>
> make
>
> generating generator-i386-mingw32.def
>
> compiling generator.c
>
> linking shared-object json/ext/generator.so
>
> make install
>
> /usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 generator.so
>   c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/ge
>   ms/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.0/lib/json/ext /usr/bin/install: cannot remove
>   `c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
>   /gems/json-1.8.0/lib/json/ext/generator.so': Permission denied make:
>   *** [c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.0/lib/j
>   son/ext/generator.so] Error 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9 .1/gems/json-1.8.0 for
>   inspection.
>
> Results logged to
>   c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.
>   0/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out An error occurred while
>   installing json (1.8.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
>
> Make sure that
>   `gem install json -v '1.8.0'` succeeds before bundling.

I've spent a fair amount of time but still can't figure out what's wrong. Please advise.

Comment: Looks like you're on windows.  Problem seems to be with permissions?  Are you running as administrator in your command window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded and ran [Rails Installer](http://railsinstaller.org/).  This time when I ran `bundle install`, the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the white space in your Ruby path:

> **NOTE**: The path to your  must not contain any
>   whitespaces (like in “C:\Program Files\Ruby193”). This is very
>   important because whitespaces in the path to your ruby installation
>   will cause certain error messages as soon as you try to install gems
>   which require the DevKit.

https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit

hth
Frank